# best translation for несчастливая?

Tags: перевод

The first sentence of *Anna Karenina* goes as follows:

> Все счастливые семьи похожи друг на друга, каждая несчастливая семья несчастлива по-своему.

What would be a better translation of "несчастлива"?  Unhappy or miserable? Or maybe another word? The commonly used English "unhappy"  seems too weak, based on my knowledge of Polish.

Comment: I would also like to know (presuming this is what you are thinking) whether there is a sense of 'unlucky' there.

Comment: Why knowledge of Polish? It's Russian...

Answer (score 6):

`"Unhappy"` seems to be the best translation for `"несчастливая"`.
`"Miserable"` would be a good fit for `"несчастная"`, but that's a stronger word.

Answer (score 6):

The authors of three translations have opted for **unhappy**

> “Happy families are all alike; every unhappy family is unhappy in its
> own way,” wrote Garnett.
>
> “All happy families are alike; each unhappy family is unhappy in its
> own way,” wrote Pevear and Volokhonsky.
>
> Here, meanwhile, is Schwartz: “All happy families resemble one
> another; each unhappy family is unhappy in its own way.”

[Source](https://www.nytimes.com/2014/12/28/books/review/new-translations-of-tolstoys-anna-karenina.html)